# Sending application emails method - SMTP vs. Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, .net, sendmail, exchangewebservices, smtpclient

I have an ASP.Net application, that needs to send Email.

Can someone present the Advantages and Disadvantages of sending those Emails via:

`SmtpClient (using System.Net.Mail)` vs `ExchangeService (using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices)`

One thing I know is that if I send Via SmtpClient the emails does not saved in "Sent Items" folder of the Exchange Server - and If I send them via EWS (Exchange Web Services) - They are Saved there

any other issus?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Exchange mail services uses the MAPI Emailing protocol while SMTP uses POP or IMAP Emailing protocol. You can refer [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/99423/email-whats-the-difference-in-pop3-imap-and-exchange/) for more information on the protocols and use which one works for you.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Exchange Web Services does not 'use MAPI'. It allows communication with Exchange via SOAP web services, so the protocols are HTTP/HTTPS, SMTP does not 'use POP or IMAP'. SMTP is the underlying protocol that internet mail uses. POP is a protocol that email clients use to retrieve emails. IMAP is similar, but more fully featured.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending an email as an exchange user it makes sense to use EWS - it will perform an action similar as if that user sent an email using the Outlook client.

If you are sending an email and you don't have an exchange user credentials, you can still use the SMTP to send an email to some account on the exchange server.